# Cannot connect multiple PS4 controllers through bluetooth

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I have two PS4 controllers but I'm unable to connect both by bluetooth on my iMac and Mac Book Pro, both running Mojave.

I can pair one of them (say A) and, as soon as I do it, the other one (say B) is not recognized through bluetooth. When I set it to be discoverable, the white light blinks for a while and nothing happens. The weirdest thing is that if I disconnect A and try to connect B, it won't be recognizable unless I run:

`sudo rm -R /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist`

So what happens now is that I can pair A to my iMac and B to my  Mac Book Pro, but not both to neither of them.

I have been googling this problem for a while but haven't found a solution or even a reason for this to make sense.

Comment: Just wondering, have you checked out these related questions [1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/228082/168832), [2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/312263/168832) just in case there's anything useful in the answers/comments?

Comment: I have checked them, but none help me, unfortunately, @Monomeeth.

Answer (score 2):

I successfully managed to connect 2 DualShock 4 on my Mac mini 2012 running High Sierra 10.13.6 using a Bluetooth Dongle (not with the builtin Mac mini BT controller).

Both gamepads could not be connected simultaneously as described in the question.
Purchased Mac-compatible Bluetooth USB dongle (https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B009IQB3US/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1). You need to check for Broadcom chipset to be supported by Mac (no driver needed). Then voilà! Both gamepads connected / working at the same time.

Recommendations:

- Delete all BT devices paired from Mac
- Make sure Mac picked up the BT dongle as controller vs builtin one (ALT-click on BT icon and check for MAC address change).
- Reconnect / pair BT devices
- I had to reset one of my DualShock (https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-reset-ps4-controller-4174025)

PS: could not answer similar question [Use more than one PS4 Dualshock controller over bluetooth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312263/use-more-than-one-ps4-dualshock-controller-over-bluetooth) due to lack of reputation

Hope it helps.